# Google Sheets Script to count the number of cells with a specific background color, from a different Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, background-color, highlight

I'm looking for help with a spreadsheet I'm working on. I need a script that will count the number of cells with a specific background color. Searches have led me to a number of scripts that work, but they only will count the colored cells in that particular Google Sheet.

I'm not sure if the script needs updating, or if my formula is incorrect. For sake of simplicity, let's say I have two Google Sheets I'm looking at, with one tab in each:

Google Sheet 1 = GS1 /// Tab = Sheet1
Google Sheet 2 = GS2 /// Tab = Sheet2

I need a formula to put into GS1, that will count the number of cells with a specific background color from a range listed in GS2.

The script that I have in GS1 is listed below:

```
    /**
    * @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
    * @param {range} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
    * @return {number}
    * @customfunction
    */

    function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
      var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
      var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
      var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
      
      var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
      var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
      var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
      var values = range.getValues();
  
      var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
      var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
      var color = colorCell.getBackground();
       
      var count = 0;
      
      for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
        for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
          if( bg[i][j] == color )
            count=count+1;
      return count;
    };
```

And the formula I'm using in GS1 to pull the count is listed below:

```
    =countColoredCells(IMPORTRANGE("GS2 URL", "Sheet2!E:E"), "GS1!Z3")
```

I'm received an #ERROR! that says:
"Exception: Range not found (line 14)"

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my script, or my formula, or if it is something that is just not feasible. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Excel and python. Google sheets has much harder time and more issues with its api versus excel you can directly open up the two files from your local machine. Regarding your error it's difficult to say without looking at the spreadsheet but I feel like it has something to do with active sheet object not having any color?

Answer (score 0):

```
function countbg(id = "1Y2mT5ahv2GYcnmAw8UyRbuCUDVmPDTXw8qtIIehEDac") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const bg = ss.getActiveRange().getBackground();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  let cnt = 0;
  tss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    Logger.log(sh.getName());
    sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds().forEach(r => {
      r.forEach(c => {
        if(c == bg) {
          cnt++;
        }
      })
    })
  })
  Logger.log(cnt)
}
```

Select a cell with the color you wish to count and enter the id of the spreadsheet you wish to count in.

References:

- [ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)